# EntityFrameworkCore Populate Property With Polymorphic Association

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table `Venue` which can have multiple `Media` items on it. Media can be for any number of different tables, so we have 2 properties on it, `MediaType` to specify which table it's for (content, venue, venueCategory, contact), and `MediaTypeID` for specifying which item in that table it's for.

How can we populate myVenue.Media when we load our Venues?

We have the following which seems close...

MyDBContext.cs:

```
builder.Entity<Venue>()
                .HasMany<Media>(x => x.Medias)
                .WithOne(m => m.Venue)
                .HasForeignKey(m => m.MediaTypeID);
```

Media.cs looks something like:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int MediaID { get; set; }
public string URL { get; set; }
public int MediaType { get; set; }
public int MediaTypeID { get; set; }
public Venue Venue { get; set; }
```

Venue.cs has:
`public virtual ICollection<Media> Medias { get; set; }`

And then to use the code we're using:

`db.Venue.Include(x => x.Medias)`

The issue with this is that it doesn't compare on the Media's MediaType property, so we could end up taking in Contact, or Venue Media if they have the same ID.

We could compare in a `.Where()` after every `.Include`, but it seems there should surely be a way to do it just the once in the DBContext?

To summarize, my ideal usage would be to specify:

```
builder.Entity<Venue>()
                .HasMany<Media>(x => x.Medias)
                .WithOne(m => m.Venue)
                .HasForeignKey(m => m.MediaTypeID && m.MediaType==2);
```

**UPDATE:**
From feedback in comments it seems this is not possible as EF "only supports associations which can be expressed by db FK relationship. – Ivan Stoev"

Comment: How is that possible for two Media records to have the same ID? It's a key and it should be unique. And if ID is not enough to guarantee uniqueness of record, then you probably should use compound key. E.g. MediaID + MediaTypeID

Comment: Two media can't have the same ID. But a Venue, and a VenueCategory could both have ID 1, and MediaTypeID would be the same for both of those, so yeah, MediaID and MediaTypeID are what is used.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you - it's not clear how VenueCategory is related to your query.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I didn't realise I hadn't added that as an example of one of the tables that could be using the Media table to store it's media items

Comment: Sounds like you're missing MediaType from your foreign key if I understand correctly, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961148/how-to-associate-one-table-to-many-parents-using-ef-code-first).

Comment: Looks like you are trying to model a polymorphic association in your `Media` entity and associated db table, which is not possible in EF since it only supports associations which can be expressed by db FK relationship.

Comment: Thank @Ivan Stoev, that sounds very clear. Will avoid using this style relationships in future so and do nullable columns for each possible associated type.